# Object-based Classification in Orfeo ToolBox

Tags: qgis, classification, image-segmentation, otb-applications

I have a multispectral camera with 5 bands (r, g, b, red edge, NIR) and I would like to classify plants object based with Orfeo ToolBox. I am flying with the drone close to the plants and have an image resolution of about 0.01 m per pixel. I guess I have to do a segmentation first, then an object based classification. What steps and models in OTB do I have to follow?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are four steps to perform an object-based classification in OTB:

1) Image segmentation

otbcli_Segmentation

note that there is also an external module with the Baatz and Schape criterion : http://tully.ups-tlse.fr/lassallep/grm/tree/master

2) Feature extraction in order to compute object-based variables for the classification

otbcli_ZonalStatistics

3) training the classifier to build a model based on training samples

otbcli_TrainVectorClassifier

4) Applying a model to the feature

otbcli_VectorClassifier

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed description of single steps: [Object-based classification (Tutorial)](http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Object-based_classification_(Tutorial))

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackexchange. Could you please add a short description to your link, so that your answer can still provide information in case the link is broken?